# Unable to rename copy of Masterpage for sharepoint 2013 onprem site collection in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I want to add text on top of all pages after site[sharepoint 2013- on premise] title for that,
I am trying to do changes in masterpage by taking the  copy of master page html [seattle.html]  file for 2013 site collection using Sharepoint designer. When trying to rename, not able to do that and automatically  reverting to old name[seattle_copy(1).html] .**I'm not getting any errors while trying to rename** and  able to do checkin ,checkout or open file in "Advanced Mode".

I have a site collection admin access.

Can any one help me on to resolve the issue.

Comment: You're trying to change the name of the file from "seattle_copy(1).html" to "seattle.html"?

Comment: Im giving some  another name to  seattle_copy(1).html like "Test MastePage".But when i give and leave it , automatically it is reverting to" seattle_copy(1)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to rename the duplicate copy "seattle.copy(1).html" file in "All Files -->_Catalogs->MasterPage folder" in Sharepoint Designer.Not directly in MasterPages Folder.